# Cancelling an order programmatically and notify customer

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm using an extension which cancels an order after X days old. However, customers are not being notified about it. See my code:

```
if($order_bis->canUnhold()) {
    $order_bis->unhold()->save();
}
if ($order_bis->canCancel()) {
    Mage::log( '[kinento-reminder] Canceling order '.$order_bis->getIncrementId().' ('.$cancelprepaid->getTimestamp().' > '.$orderdate.')', null, 'kinento.log', true );
    $order_bis->cancel();
    $order_bis->addStatusToHistory($order_bis->getStatus(), 'Cancelado automaticamente', true);
    $order_bis->save();
    Mage::getSingleton( 'adminhtml/session' )->addSuccess( Mage::helper( 'reminder' )->__( 'Order %d canceled', $order_bis->getIncrementId() ) );
}
```

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below after `$order_bis->save()` add below code

```
 $order_bis->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify=true, $comment='Cancelado automaticamente');
```

This code is sending order update email.

Comment: Great, I'll try it, thanks. Just a doubt: in the history comments on the order page, the same comment was added twice by the module. So, that line "$order->cancel()" adds a comment automatically?

Comment: just remove $order_bis->addStatusToHistory($order_bis->getStatus(), 'Cancelado automaticamente', true);

Comment: Done! So now I will wait until a new pending order to be cancelled. Do you know some online reference where I can find all order functions?

Comment: And also, let's see if you can help me with something else: I would like to use a custom email template for cancelled orders and not just the order update email. Do you know how to?

Comment: Please accept this answe